# Notify inactive users (who have not opened the app for 7 days) even if Android app gets killed or runs in background

Tags: android, notifications, periodic-task, user-inactivity

I have a requirement where I need to notify inactive users (who have not opened the app for 7 days). This means the notification must be sent if the app is in background for 7 days or the app has been killed and not used for 7 days.

I followed an algorithm using `AlarmManager` similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22710380/13572191) but the notifications are not sent if the app gets killed. I tried to integrate `BroadcastReceiver` as shown below but it creates an infinite loop when I call it from `OnDestroy()` of `CheckRecentRun`class (because it destroys itself periodically). Also, as I learnt from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18361887/13572191), onDestroy() does not always get called when app is killed.

```
public class TimerRestarterBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TimerRestarterBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "Service has stopped");
    context.startService(new Intent(context, CheckRecentRun.class));
}
}
```

Is there any simpler and effective way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible scenario using WorkManager:

- You create a task that send notification in 7 days
- Every time user uses app change time of the old task to a new one after 7 days

Comment: WorkManager is not guaranteed to work. It stops working if killed by OS in some devices like xiaomi, huawei

Answer (score 0):

You can try workmanager schedule work . I hope this will solve your problem .
To know more please check it. [Check it](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)