# Send notification if user is inactive in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How to send a notification on user if is inactive for 3 days on my app?. I'm begginer on android developer so i can't find any easy (and corerct) way to do that

Comment: I think you need to set up Firebase Cloud Messaging

Comment: maybe this could be helpful:
[How to send notification if user inactive for 3 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709751/how-to-send-notification-if-user-inactive-for-3-days/22710380)

Comment: @modos Thanks but is saying when it can''t run this process on the background :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use android `broadcast receiver` to do this

For more information you can read the [official android documentaion](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwibk9Ca_KbwAhVs_rsIHX7OBJsQFjABegQIBBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fcontent%2FBroadcastReceiver&usg=AOvVaw0q4wTdhLTGnpxTKMD5mZXl)